# Log Execution Time in System.Data.Linq.DataContext like in EntityFramework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, logging, linq-to-sql, execution-time

I have found [an article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464.aspx) how to log execution time from on EntityFramework 6. It is simple, just set the Log property. I like it.

I use Linq2Sql in my project, mainly because of historical purposes and I don't need to migrate it to EntityFramework. There is a Log Property in System.Data.Linq.DataContext as well which does almost the same thing like the Log property in EntityFramework, except that there is no execution time.

Is there a way, how to turn on the execution time in System.Data.Linq.DataContext? Can I switch System.Data.Linq.DataContext to something from EntityFramework without migrating the rest of code?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some time-stamp references here - I haven't tried it myself though...https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464.aspx#Log

Comment: That is exactly what I am asked for. The link you suggested is about System.Data.Entity.DbContext. and use System.Data.Linq.DataContext. My question is if I can use System.Data.Entity.DbContext instead of Data.Linq.DataContext?

Answer (score 0):

Finally it seems that the Linq to SQL need to be [migrated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975477/migrating-from-linq-to-sql-to-entity-framework-4-0-tips-documentation-etc) to Entity Framework, which can be more complicated then I thought.